# Bessel Function in Tumor Model, Modelling H+ Diffusion

Tags: bessel-functions

I am trying to implement the algorithm described in this paper as a computer algorithm:
http://europepmc.org/abstract/med/8971186

In particular, I am interested in equation L:

[image]

I am provided all values, but the paper does not explain how to solve for I and K values. I am not a mathematician and don't think my knowledge of maths is sufficient to solve these type of equations, but was wondering if anybody could point me toward the right resources?